# What actuators do the me-shifter gear shifting system uses?

Tags: automotive-engineering, gears

I have a shifter kart (125ccm kz2) with 6 gears.
What I want to do is to change gears from the steering wheel. Like in the system mentioned in the question.

I have the electrical and electronic system needed but I need a fast and powerful actuator (using 12VDC or 5-6VDC, 3 cm travel, going both ways, about 30Nm)

I was thinking about using just the actuator from one of these systems (don't have that much money to spend on it), but I don't know what it is.
This is the website: http://me-shifter.com/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems very similar to a product recommendation question (which would be off-topic for the site) in the sense that you're asking about the components of a specific product. Answers could easily become obsolete and won't have much lasting value. You'd probably be better off contacting the manufacturer and asking them what actuators they use, although they might not be willing to tell you/they might use proprietary actuators

Comment: The [technical description](http://me-shifter.com/?page_id=43) uses the term "servomotor" several times, so that's probably what they're using.

Comment: I noticed the servo mention, but i cannot find any that works like theirs.